# Golang build tags for a particular Go version possible?

Tags: go, build, compilation, tags

Using build tags alone is it possible to target a particular Go version in a file?

// +build go1.7

eg. with the adding of golang.org/x/net/context to the standard lib, I have some code that I want to update to use the std lib context ( when it's released ) but be able to maintain backward compatibility for those that have not yet updated.

I know there are many ways to control this including the branch name and go get, just wondering if there's a way using build tags.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Thanks, I searched around but didn't find anything; this is exactly what I was looking for. +1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put the code that depends on contexts in a file with the following build tag. This code is compiled for Go 1.7 and onward.

```
// +build go1.7
```

Put the backwards compatibility code in a file with the following build tag. This code is used for all versions of Go before 1.7.

```
// +build !go1.7
```